# Count how often a value in a cell in one specific column is not the same as the value in the same row of a specific other column

Tags: excel, sum, excel-formula, worksheet-function, countif

Both ColumnA and ColumnB are blank except for `O` and `R` (individually).

**How can I count the number of times a row contains `O` in ColumnA and `R` in the same row of ColumnB together with a row that contains `R` in ColumnA and `O` in the same row of ColumnB?**

For example the result for the example below should be `5` as indicated by the asterisks:

[image: SO28856866 example]

All cells not shown are blank.

The second row is counted because A2 does not equal B2. The first row is *not* counted because both A1 and B1 contain just `O`. The fifth row is counted because within a given row it does not matter whether `O` is in ColumnA and `R` in ColumnB or `R` in ColumnA and `O` in ColumnB. The seventh row is *not* counted because both A7 and B7 contain just `R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"O",B:B,"<>"&"O")+COUNTIFS(A:A,"R",B:B,"<>"&"R")
```

For equal:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"O",B:B,"O")+COUNTIFS(A:A,"R",B:B,"R")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for a count of rows where A is not equal to B you can use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A50<>B1:B50)*1)
```

Sumproduct will compare each row in A1 through A50 with the values in A and B. If they are not equal it will add 1 to the overall count, counting for each row 1 though 50.

If you would like an indicator in Column C to tell you if A and B is not equal for each row you can just use:

```
=A1<>B1
```

Put that in C1 and copy down for each row.